# Autopilot setup error

Tags: server, juju, maas, kvm-virtualization, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to setup a small cloud on QEMU/KVM to tryout MAAS/Autopilot/JUJU.

I have 4 VMs:

1) Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64: MAAS controller 2.0.0+bzr5189-0ubuntu1

2) Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64: node 1 (Deployed)

3) Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64: node 2 (Deployed)

4) Ubuntu 14.04.5 x64: node 3 (Ready) ==> autopilot install target

So I made available the third node in "Ready" status in MAAS and tried to install Autopilot on it from the MAAS controller, bootstrap worked and it deployed Ubuntu Trusty automatically on the available node 3, I have SSH access.

[OpenStack Autopilot panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV8V4.png)

But I get this error in the process:

```
misterz@controller:~$ conjure-up openstack
Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/ubuntui/ev.py", line 83, in run
    cls.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1328, in run
    raise self._exc_info[0](self._exc_info[1]).with_traceback(self._exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    event_loop, callback, self.get_available_raw_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 493, in parse_input
    callback(processed, processed_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 403, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 503, in process_input
    k = self._topmost_widget.keypress(self.screen_size, k)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 643, in keypress
    return self._current_widget.keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1128, in keypress
    return self.body.keypress( (maxcol, remaining), key )
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/ui/views/welcome.py", line 35, in keypress
    return super().keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 836, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol,), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 621, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress(maxvals, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 2269, in keypress
    key = w.keypress((mc,) + size[1:], key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 535, in keypress
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/ui/views/welcome.py", line 72, in done
    self.cb(result.label)
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/controllers/welcome.py", line 31, in finish
    self.app.controllers['jujucontroller'].render()
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/controllers/jujucontroller.py", line 153, in render
    Juju.switch(c)
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/juju.py", line 241, in switch
    cls.login(True)
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/juju.py", line 96, in login
    password = account['users'][current_user]['password']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/conjure-up", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('conjure-up==0.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'conjure-up')()
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/app.py", line 222, in main
    app.start()
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/app.py", line 171, in start
    EventLoop.run()
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/ubuntui/ev.py", line 83, in run
    cls.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1328, in run
    raise self._exc_info[0](self._exc_info[1]).with_traceback(self._exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    event_loop, callback, self.get_available_raw_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 493, in parse_input
    callback(processed, processed_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 403, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 503, in process_input
    k = self._topmost_widget.keypress(self.screen_size, k)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 643, in keypress
    return self._current_widget.keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1128, in keypress
    return self.body.keypress( (maxcol, remaining), key )
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/ui/views/welcome.py", line 35, in keypress
    return super().keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 836, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol,), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 621, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress(maxvals, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 2269, in keypress
    key = w.keypress((mc,) + size[1:], key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 535, in keypress
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/ui/views/welcome.py", line 72, in done
    self.cb(result.label)
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/controllers/welcome.py", line 31, in finish
    self.app.controllers['jujucontroller'].render()
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/controllers/jujucontroller.py", line 153, in render
    Juju.switch(c)
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/juju.py", line 241, in switch
    cls.login(True)
  File "/usr/share/conjure-up/conjure/juju.py", line 96, in login
    password = account['users'][current_user]['password']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

It seems I am missing some user/password ? I didn't get prompt for anything else than my MAAS host and MAAS key.

Comment: What instructions are you following? http://conjure-up.io/docs/en/users/#getting-started ?  Mentioning Autopilot is pretty specific to 14.04 I believe.  As it has been replaced with conjure-up in 16.04.

Comment: Instructions from: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud, my MAAS is on 16.04 and my target for Autopilot is 14.04, is this a problem ? I am using `conjure-up openstack` from the MAAS controller.

Comment: That problem is juju on 14.04 is 1.25 and 16.04 uses 2.0, I'm pretty sure.  If you use conjure your machines should be 16.04, if you're using autopilot everything should be 14.04.

Comment: I don't understand why you are all tagging this as duplicate, it is not even remotely related. Just because you see a python error with the installer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started from scratch with everything running on Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS amd64 (Trusty) and the Autopilot setup is working properly.

MAAS Controller => Version 1.9.4+bzr4592

Autopilot / Landscape ==> Version 16.06

I followed this guide: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2013/11/15/interested-in-maas-and-juju-heres-how-to-try-it-in-a-vm/